# Hibernate Search Default Directory Provider

Tags: indexing, lucene, directory, hibernate-search, provider

I just asked myself what is the default value for the Hibernate Search directory provider?

I've uncomment the property setting "hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" inside my persistence.xml. Hibernate Search is still working. I just ask myself at which place the Lucene index is stored. Is "ram" the default directory provider if no other value is provided?

I did not find any information about a default or fall back value for this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default directory provider is "filesystem".

Source: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/a411f7b984cfabd2f8fd4b6c743beef8646a1d82/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/store/impl/DefaultDirectoryProviderService.java#L23

Comment: Correct. And it will create folders with the index name in the current process directory: ".".